# I don't know why When I click the button "Click = Past" on my HTML program the green character image doesn't show up I tried to this in Khan academy

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There is supposed to be a green character image when you click "Click = Past" the same one you would see at the start of the program. The character image is most likely to show if you past the code in khan academy, but if you wish not to do that feel free to paste it somewhere else like replit and change the images. This is my first time using buttons I just improvised on some stuff(I did everything correct though and checked my code a million times and can't find anything wrong.). Also this is my first time using stack overflow feel free to tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

My code:

```js
var leafy = function() {
  $("img").attr("src", "https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/landscapes/beach-with-palm-trees.png")
    .css("position", "relative")
    .css("top", "0")
    .css("left", "0")
    .css("z-index", "1");

  $(".leafers").attr("src", "https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/avatars/leafers-ultimate.png")
    .css("position", "absolute")
    .css("top", "210px")
    .css("left", "378px")
    .css("z-index", "3");

  $("p").html("Life is to short to waste time,<br> I should have done something with mine.<br> It's too late now. <strong>-Leafers ultimate</strong>")
    .css("background-color", "rgb(0, 255, 230)")
    .css("color", "rgb(0, 0, 0")
    .css("font-family", "Georgia")
    .css("top", "209px")
    .css("left", "148px")
    .css("z-index", "4");

  $(".past")
    .text("Click = Past")
    .css("color", "white")
    .css("top", "354px")
    .css("left", "22px")
    .css("z-index", "2");

}



var omg = function() {


  $("img").attr("src", "https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/seasonal/fireworks-over-harbor.png")
    .css("top", "0px")
    .css("left", "0px")
    .css("z-index", "1");

  $("img").attr("src", "https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/seasonal/fireworks-over-harbor.png")
    .css("position", "absolute")
    .css("top", "0px")
    .css("left", "0px")
    .css("z-index", "2");

  $("p").html("Lets party and have fun.<br> <strong>-Leafers seedling</strong>")
    .css("background-color", "rgb(245, 135, 245)")
    .css("color", "rgb(255, 205, 3)")
    .css("font-family", "cursive")
    .css("z-index", "5");

  $("button").text(Click = Future)
    .css("z-index", "4")
    .addClass("Future");


  $("button")
    .css("top", "359px")
    .css("left", "22px")
    .css("z-index", "3")
    .addClass("past");
}


$(".Future").on("click", function() {
  console.log("yay");
  leafy();
});

$(".past").on("click", function() {
  console.log("lesss gooo");
  omg();
});
```

```css
.leafers {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 378px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.seedling {
  background-color: rgb(245, 135, 245);
  color: rgb(255, 205, 3);
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 233px;
  left: 264px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.scape {
  z-index: 2;
}

.Future {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 379px;
  left: 22px;
}

.past {
  background-color: rgb(10, 26, 252);
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 386px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 26px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="scape" src="https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/seasonal/fireworks-over-harbor.png">
<img src="https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/avatars/leafers-seedling.png" class="leafers">
<p class="seedling">
  "Lets party and have fun.<br>
  <strong>-Leafers seedling"</strong>
</p>
<button class="Future">Click=Future</button>
<button Class="past"></button>
```

Comment: Copied your code to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLjkdvub/).

Comment: One issue is that you're using `$(".img")` which will replace *both* images,  change to `$("img.scape")` to change just the background image.

Comment: Looks like your main issue is that in `omg()` you don't set the `.leafers` image, instead you set `img` twice to harbor, so there's no code to reset back to -seedling.png.   Replacing the 2nd `$("img")` in `omg()` and it seems to work ok: https://jsfiddle.net/nLjkdvub/1/

Comment: Nothing particularly wrong with your question.  I notice you haven't, so do read the [tour].  Minor improvement: could do with putting your code in a *snippet* (similar to jsfiddle) and breaking your single paragraph of text into multiple paragraphs.   Suspect this will be closed "as a typo".

Comment: Thank you so much you have no idea how much this means to me I have been stuck on this for quiet a while. Anything I can do to help?

Comment: Just a FYI, one way you can simplify your code, and make it faster, is to only use pure JavaScript or jQuery to add or remove CSS classes from the elements you are trying to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a definite error in your code (`Click = Future` should be text, so delimited with quotes), but this is not the only problem.

The other problem is that when you set the "past" via JavaScript, you don't use the "leafy" character image, but the fireworks (this counts as a typo, in my opinion).

```js
function omg() {
  $(".scape").attr('src', 'https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/seasonal/fireworks-over-harbor.png')
    .css("position", "relative")
    .css("top", "0")
    .css("left", "0")
    .css("z-index", "1");

  $(".leafers").attr('src', 'https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/avatars/leafers-seedling.png')
    .css("position", "absolute")
    .css("top", "210px")
    .css("left", "378px")
    .css("z-index", "3");

  $('.seedling').html('"Lets party and have fun.<br><strong>-Leafers seedling"</strong>')
    .css("background-color", "rgb(0, 255, 230)")
    .css("color", "rgb(0, 0, 0")
    .css("font-family", "Georgia")
    .css("top", "209px")
    .css("left", "148px")
    .css("z-index", "4");

  $('.future').text('Click = future')
  $('.past').text('')
}

function leafy() {
  $(".scape").attr("src", "https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/landscapes/beach-with-palm-trees.png")
    .css("top", "0px")
    .css("left", "0px")
    .css("z-index", "1");

  $(".leafers").attr("src", "https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/avatars/leafers-ultimate.png")
    .css("position", "absolute")
    .css("top", "210px")
    .css("left", "378px")
    .css("z-index", "3");

  $(".seedling").html("Lets party and have fun.<br> <strong>-Leafers seedling</strong>")
    .css("background-color", "rgb(245, 135, 245)")
    .css("color", "rgb(255, 205, 3)")
    .css("font-family", "cursive")
    .css("z-index", "5");

  $(".future").text("Click = Future")
    .css("z-index", "4")
    .addClass("Future");


  $(".past").text("Click = Past")
    .css("top", "359px")
    .css("left", "22px")
    .css("z-index", "3")
    .addClass("past");
}

// to get the first setup
omg()

$(".future").on("click", function() {
  console.log("yay");
  leafy();
});

$(".past").on("click", function() {
  console.log("lesss gooo");
  omg();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.leafers {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 378px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.seedling {
  background-color: rgb(245, 135, 245);
  color: rgb(255, 205, 3);
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 233px;
  left: 264px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.scape {
  z-index: 2;
}

.future {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 379px;
  left: 22px;
}

.past {
  background-color: rgb(10, 26, 252);
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 386px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 26px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="scape" src="">
<img class="leafers" src="">
<p class="seedling"></p>
<button class="future"></button>
<button class="past"></button>
```

TBH, I would do it totally differently. Considering the use case that I could read from the code and behavior, I'd rather do it more like this (OK, I'd leave jQuery out, but hey, YOLO):

```js
// utility functions
const getImgHtml = ({ src }) => `<img src="${src}" />`
const setImgHtml = ({ selector, html }) => jQuery(selector).html(html)
const setSceneImg = ({ src, selector }) => {
  const html = getImgHtml({ src })
  setImgHtml({ selector, html })
}

// setting the scene function
const setScene = ({ bgSrc, charSrc, btnPastShow, btnFutureShow }) => {
  setSceneImg({ src: bgSrc, selector: ".background" })
  setSceneImg({ src: charSrc, selector: ".character" })
  jQuery('.btn.past').css('display', btnPastShow)
  jQuery('.btn.future').css('display', btnFutureShow)
}

// creating the two different scenes
const omg = {
  bgSrc: 'https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/seasonal/fireworks-over-harbor.png',
  charSrc: 'https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/avatars/leafers-seedling.png',
  btnPastShow: 'none',
  btnFutureShow: 'block',
}

const leafy = {
  bgSrc: 'https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/landscapes/beach-with-palm-trees.png',
  charSrc: 'https://cdn.kastatic.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/avatars/leafers-ultimate.png',
  btnPastShow: 'block',
  btnFutureShow: 'none',
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // loading the first scene
  setScene(omg)

  // button click handlers
  $('.btn.future').on('click', function() {
    setScene(leafy)
  })
  $('.btn.past').on('click', function() {
    setScene(omg)
  })
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: min-content;
}

.character {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
}

.btn.future {
  bottom: 40px;
  background: red;
  color: white
}

.btn.past {
  bottom: 55px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="character"></div>
  <button class="btn future">Future</button>
  <button class="btn past">Past</button>
</div>
```